# What is the UID (user id) & GID (group id) that Samba Service using?

Tags: samba

What is the default UID (user in) and GID (group id) that Samba service using? For an example, `Apache2` runs as `www-data`, likewise what is the UID that **Samba** service using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ps -eo uid,gid,args|grep myprocess` helps you to find the UID and GID of a running process. For samba, replace `myprocess` by `smbd` and `nmbd`.

Answer (score 1):

Samba runs as `root`, and when you connect, it changes to your user.